# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil for one specific date

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter

My date formatter return nil for one specific date: "20 Mar, 1998".

```
+ (NSDate*)dateFromString:(NSString*)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    if ([WPRConverter isUropeanMetrics])
        [df setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];
    else
        [df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
    return [df dateFromString:date];
}
```

I've checked near dates and all being returned correctly:

- "20 Mar, 1997"
- "20 Mar, 1999"
- "21 Mar, 1998"
- "19 Mar, 1998"

[image]

My Locale is "en_US".

Using [NSDateFormatter getObjectValue:forString:range:error:] gets me error:

> The value “20 Mar, 1998” is invalid. FailureReason: The value “20 Mar,
>   1998” is invalid. RecoverySuggestion: Please provide a valid value.
>   RecoveryOptions:  Code: 2048

Comment: Could you please specify your locale?

Comment: I've updated the question with locale.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, are you sure your code does not go through the `MMM dd, yyyy` branch?

Comment: Yep I'm sure. I also attached image with expressions of the same type which differ only by year or by day. I'm not sure but result of some expressions may help. I can see that date being translated to UTC time. But I still can't figure out the probulem.

Comment: You can try to use 
`-[NSDateFormatter getObjectValue:forString:range:error:]` method instead. That one will give you the `NSError` if parsing fails.

Comment: Well, one hint is that the local offset from UTC apparently changes from the 19th to the 21st. Presumably, the 20th is the start of DST in your time zone in 1998. My guess is that `NSDateFormatter` is assuming a time that doesn't exist on that day because the clocks "sprang forward" past it. You can try `-getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` and see what error it returns, if any.

Comment: Yes, it's true that when there is no time, that the assumption usually is that time is zero. The 20th of March could be the day when daylight saving time changes.

Comment: So assuming the issue related to daylight, how this can be handled in order to resolve the issue?

Comment: Using -[NSDateFormatter getObjectValue:forString:range:error:] gets me error: The value “20 Mar, 1998” is invalid.
FailureReason: The value “20 Mar, 1998” is invalid.
RecoverySuggestion: Please provide a valid value.
RecoveryOptions: 
Code: 2048

Comment: It seems this is really related to the time zone, see (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/israel/karmiel?year=1998) (since I see you are from Tel Aviv). I would try to change `formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone  timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]`.

Comment: Sultan, thanks. This worked. You can post it as answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to `timeZone` in Israel which had a day light saving time change (see http://timeanddate.com/time/change/israel/karmiel?year=1998).

Changing the time zone to GMT:

```
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]
```

should fix the problem.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Note, of course, that the resulting `NSDate` will be a different time (and maybe calendar date) than the first moment of 20 Mar, 1998 in your Israeli time zone. What precise moment in time are you really interested in? You might want to create an `NSDateComponents` from the date you get, as interpreted in the same calendar and UTC, then create a new `NSDate` from those components but using your original time zone.